# Are query strings for cache busting okay to use?

Tags: caching

Tools like [tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com/) and [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) recommend that you:

> Remove query strings from static resources

Pingdom links to [a page on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules) which doesn't mention it at all. I'm guessing it used to, but they probably changed it. And GTmetrix links to their own [page](https://gtmetrix.com/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources.html) which mentions the popular [Squid Proxy Server](http://www.squid-cache.org/) (<= v 3.0) as not caching resources with query strings. This also seems to be the only reason people mention throughout the web, though articles are from like 2008 - 2011.

If someone can confirm my thought process,.... Squid is server side as all these caching proxies are. So if we're setting up our own server (let's say on something like DigitalOcean for example) we would know if we're using these proxies and we would know what version we are using and if they are a problem for query strings. Right? So basically we are in control as it's server-side.

If this is the case then, query strings aren't an issue. but I'll ask anyways...

**So in 2016, are using query strings still an issue?**

Just a side note, I know other methods of cache busting, but query strings would just be faster for new projects.

Comment: Squid is not "server-side".   It's a pass-through proxy/cache.   You won't in general know if your end users are getting your website through zero, one, or Many squid-like proxies.

Comment: Also don't count on caches not caching just because there is a query string present.   Use proper cache control.

Comment: @BadZen Cool thanks for the info